# storing sensitive values in a secure location

Tags: php, security, api

I know this is probably a really simpleton question so apologies but I'm trying to learn new things.

I'm playing around with API calls and a tutorial I'm reading is advising that for sensitive info like passwords, username etc I should be "storing these values in a secure location other than your web server document root and setting the file permissions so that only the system user that executes your ecommerce application can access it."

That all sounds like a spiffing idea, but I'm not completely sure how to go about it. Do I have a php file with for example define('PASSWORD', 'xxxxxx'); etc in it and then call that from somewhere? If so how and where should I put it?

I know you're probably wondering why I'm playing around with an API if I don't know how to do that and indeed it is a strange route that I've come down to find myself here, yet here I am, and that is what I don't know.

any help would be most gratefully received :) Julia

Edit: by the way assume I know nothing - because I really do know very little ;)

Comment: does your app have a DB connection?

Comment: It depends on what kind of data your trying to store and how you plan to read it. Passwords for databases for example, can be stored, as you mentioned, as constants in an include file.

Comment: Hi guys, yeah my app has a DB connection. What needs to happen is I need to have a php file and in it I construct an array full of NVPs. It's for paypal so I need the method, my api_sig, api_username and api_password. These are the things that I'm meant to keep secret somewhere. I'm not really sure what to do. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What they mean is, it's ok to put your user/pass in a file that gets included in your app, but that file should be some place other than where your index.php is. For example, given the directory structure:

```
/home/alex/site/public/
/home/alex/site/lib/
/home/alex/site/data/
```

In the public dir, I'd put my index.php, my CSS, my JS, and images. And that's it. The meat of the PHP app would go into the lib dir, and be referenced by the PHP include_path. Extra files like configs might go into the data dir. Then, your vhost document_root points to the public dir. So, a user hitting http://alex.com/index.php gets the right file, but since the data and lib dirs are up a level from the document_root, nobody can grab http://alex.com/data/secret.txt.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply. I understand what you're saying. My problem is I'm not sure exactly how I reference the stuff in the site/data folder from php files in site/public. Is there some sort of global thing where I can define things in site/data and they are just available for use as $variables everywhere except bad people can't read them or alter them?

Comment: If index.php is in `/home/alex/site/public/` then in that file you do `include('../data/yourFile.php');`

Comment: Bad people will not be able to get to your PHP code, since PHP is executed on the server... Unless, they gain access to your server and that's an entirely different issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Vitaliy. So if in yourFile.php I have define('password', 'xxxxxx'); then in any php file I have include('../data/yourFile.php'); in I'll be able to just use $password and it'll contain xxxxxx ? Is that right?

Comment: You don't need the `$` if you [DEFINE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) a constant.

Comment: If you use `set_include_path('/home/alex/lib');` then you can just do `include 'file.php';` to get /home/alex/lib/file.php.